# Tips on working with Java On Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-12.04

I am working on Java for few years but most of the time I work on Windows OS as it is my DEV environment. Now I want to work on Java+Linux environment.

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04, installed Oracle JDK, Eclipse, Netbeans...so far good.

But I am looking for resources/websites/blogs focusing on Java Development On Linux to learn more about how resolve common issues for newbies(like me), any profiling/debugging tools for java apps, tips on log files searching, identifying how many java processes are running, killing a particular java process etc.

By googling I am able to get these details individually... want to know if any websites/blogs exclusively focusing on above mentioned areas?

Comment: just start. when you encounter a concrete problem, you can then always ask SO

Comment: If you write your Java code in the right way, it should be exactly the same as programming on Windows.

Comment: @Redandwhite You are correct. Writing java code is same.. but most of time is going on small things like for creating a desktop shortcut i need to enter some command in terminal then provide shortcutname, command name...for installing NetBeans i need to kick the command from terminal(I was trying to start it by using some App Manager and failed)..anyway as I am new to Linux I think i need to spend sometime to get used to it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you are looking for a general purpose UNIX commands and are not specific to Java or even Linux. All the Java command are the same under Windows and Linux and if you use an IDE you don't need to worry about them

> any profiling/debugging tools for java apps

Same as Windows. Use the debug button in your IDE for debugging and `jvisualvm` for profiling or a commercial profiler like YourKit.

> tips on log files searching

Use `less` or `grep` or both. ;) You can use these in Windows using Cygwin.

> identifying how many java processes are running

Use `jps -lvm` just like in Windows.

> killing a particular java process

Use `kill {pid}`

> want to know if any websites/blogs exclusively focusing on above mentioned areas?

I wouldn't imagine there is. Look for common UNIX commands instead.

Answer (score 2):

The good news: Once you are running inside the JVM, Java **works in a very similar way** on both Windows and Linux - to some degree that is the whole point of a cross-platform language and runtime! So most of your Java experience will be entirely portable.

If you find yourself doing something Linux or Windows specific then you might want to stop and think.... is there a cross-platform way of doing this? In Java there usually is.

As a result the Linux and Windows specific things that you need to know are basically just the stuff that happens outside the JVM, e.g.:

- Starting and stopping JVMs
- How native libaries are handled
- Non-Java-specific stuff like managing the filesystem etc.

Don't have any specific resources for you to follow up, but general Linux sites should help you with most of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, There is a lot of tools to debugging java apps on linux.
I have a blog post listing the java related tools that I used for last several years.

http://hunmr.blogspot.com/2012/08/java-performance-tunning.html

and some handy commands:
http://hunmr.blogspot.com/2012/08/handy-commands-for-development.html